# First sounding rocket to reach the mesosphere?

Tags: history, atmosphere, spaceflight-firsts, sounding-rocket

The [mesosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesosphere) (the part of the atmosphere above the stratosphere where temperatures increase with altitude) is generally above the altitude reachable by balloon.  It begins somewhere around 50 km.

**When did a rocket first reach the mesosphere?**

Answer (score 6):

This was almost certainly the German V-2 rocket. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_V-2_test_launches), on the 3rd of October 1942, a V-2 reached an altitude of between 85 to 90 kilometers. The second, and the first true "[sounding rocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sounding_rocket)," was James Van Allen's [Aerobee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerobee):

> The first instrument-carrying Aerobee was the A-5, launched on March 5, 1948 from White Sands, carrying instruments for cosmic radiation research, reaching an altitude of 117.5 km.